# ITextSharp page break creates an unwanted empty page

Tags: c#, itext

**Background**

I've a document that I build up throu various steps.

In one of these steps I add content to a Document from a chapter structure I've built containing the content.

This part in particular is very simple. It simply adds the content to the document.

Sometimes my structure specifies there should be a page break, and thus document.NewPage(); gets executed. This works, usually.

We are using ITextSharp version 5.3.2.0. ( A few month old or so)

**The problem**

When document.NewPage() get's executed and is very close to the end of the document or perhaps just entered a new page I am guessing, I get an empty page with the rest of my content being added on the following page.

Only having the Document to work with at this point I can not seem to find a way how to determine if document.NewPage() should be skipped or not to work around this bug or issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be caused by three things:

1. You're using a very old version of iTextSharp. If so, please upgrade to a more recent version of iTextSharp. We don't fix obsolete versions.
2. You're using page events and contrary to what is advised in the documentation, you're adding content in the `onStartPage()` method.
3. You're using `writer.setPageEmpty(false);` which is kind of asking iText to consider an empty page as not being empty.

In all other cases, the newPage() method is ignored if you're currently on a page that doesn't have any content.

Comment: We're using version We are using ITextSharp version 5.3.2.0. When we started, I didn't have the time to read throu the entire book. Must have missed the part where it says onStartPage method should not be used to add content. This seems to be a new case and a rare one for our reports but an important one. Thanks for your answer. Will require a bit of testing and refactoring.

Comment: Just to see if it was only onStartPage() method that was causing me headache I moved the code I had in that method to OnEndPage() method. Felt like a long shot but I had to try it since it was a fast fix if it would work. Funny part it, it seems to have worked!